# Difficulty permanently replacing values in nested dictionary imported from csv

Tags: python-3.x, csv

I am (extremely) new to coding and trying to automate some processes for manipulating data as part of my PhD.

I have a CSV file from a heart rate monitor with time stored as MM:SS.s and heart rate at that time. e.g.

```
Time, Heart_rate
00:00.6, 100
00:01.0, 102
00:01.5, 102
```

I've used the CSV package to import and DictReader to get the data into an array.

```
import csv
with open('hr_data.csv', 'rU') as infile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(infile, delimiter=',')
```

The data comes in as string so I have used the following code to try to first replace heart rate a float, and then convert time (e.g. 00:05.5 - for 5.5 seconds) to a float of seconds.

```
sec = 0
for row in reader:
    row['Heart_rate'] = int(row['Heart_rate'])
    temp = row.get('Time')
    sec = (float(temp[3:7]) + (float(temp[0:2]) * 60))
    row['Time'] = sec
```

This seems to work if I print(row) afterward (everything is a float and time is in units of seconds). However when I then move forward to try to bin the data into 10sec bins, everything has reverted back to the original string and I can't seem to:

```
for row in reader:
    print(row)
```

as this just prints nothing...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post your complete code. It is very impotent to be clear about what is in the `with` block and what is not. Also, a phrase like "However when I then move forward to try to..." makes much less sense without the surrounding context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do

`with open('hr_data.csv', 'rU') as infile:
    reader = list(csv.DictReader(infile, delimiter=',’))`

and it will work like you want.

`csv.DictReader` is a generator. It goes through each line one by one, and when it’s done it is done. Because you went through all the lines in the first `for` loop, it had read all the lines from the file, and was empty.

To save a generator’s results (store *all* the lines) cast the generator to a list.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your calculations seem correct. However, once you leave the environs of the `with` construct many items are lost. For instance, `reader` is build to give you the header here; it goes away. Since it departs so do the values for `row` that come from it.  You need to arrange to save what you want as you go through the loop.

```
>>> import csv
>>> times = []
>>> heart_rates = []
>>> with open('heart.csv') as heart:
...     reader = csv.DictReader(heart, skipinitialspace=True)
...     for row in reader:
...         temp = row['Time']
...         times.append(float(temp[3:7]) + (float(temp[0:2]) * 60))
...         heart_rates.append(int(row['Heart_rate']))
... 
>>> times
[0.6, 1.0, 1.5]
>>> heart_rates
[100, 102, 102]
```

Correction: Upon discussing this with ddg I've learned that `reader` persists outside the `with`. Unfortunately though I haven't been able to re-read the rows in `reader` using `for row in reader;row` because, outside the `with` the file `heart` has been closed.

Comment: Leaving a ```with``` only removes the main variable, in this case ```heart```. Other variables assigned within a ```with``` are preserved.

Comment: @ddg, would you please expand on that. I don't understand.

Comment: Items defined within a ```with``` are not lost upon leaving. [example here](https://gist.github.com/DylanDmitri/f431699380ae85adc3524ebeb03ea4da)

Comment: @ddg: Interesting. You're right, at least in part; I hadn't noticed that. I see that in this example `reader` is still defined. However, when I attempt `for row in reader: row` I get 'ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.'

Comment: If you leave results as a ```<csv.DictReader object>```, then it’s a lazy-evaluating generator. The first time you attempt to pull information from it, it goes to the file and starts pulling information, which errors if the file is out of scope. However, if you cast the results to a list or tuple within the ```with``` block, then the file is fully loaded into memory while it is still in scope. The example I linked casts to a list, and should work.

Comment: Ah! Of course. This is what sometimes happens when I'm answering questions. The person that asked the question declared himself to be a newbie. So I tried to pitch the answer that way. Unfortunately I now see that it could have been made simpler doing it your way.